Choosing Between Intercept-Only and AR-NN Models: Justified to not use the model with the lowest RMSE/MAE?
I have created two autoregressive models for forecasting: a basic intercept-only model and an AR-NN (autoregressive neural network) model. Both models show similar performance based on recursive one-step-ahead pseudo out-of-sample RMSEs from a 70/30 train-test split, with the intercept-only model performing slightly better.The attached picture shows the forecasts: Black line = real testing data, red = Intercept-only forecast, blue = AR-NN forecast. RMSE Intercept-only = 0.018, RMSE AR-NN = 0.0209
However, the intercept-only model doesn't offer variance in its forecasts, especially compared to the AR-NN model.
Given this, does it make sense to prefer the AR-NN model to obtain future forecasts that offer more variation even though being less accurate?

This is the data (Unfortunately, the seed was not set probably, so these number differ a bit from the posted graph, still the situation remains the same):
data_test =  c( -0.0023267409, 0.0100361961,0.0031162867,-0.0104408353,0.0275584206,0.0094189017,-0.0053767755,-0.0066241215,-0.0077336373,0.0065507481,0.0108000000,-0.0010410827,0.0081810961,0.0011107585,-0.0073529412,0.0150358183,-0.0195024077,-0.0122674466,0.0106895997,-0.0095748134,0.0038797284,-0.0004852014,0.0119846596,-0.0238874346,0.0185467684,-0.0002409252,-0.0073618639,0.0065102074,-0.0103126269,0.0020259319,-0.0300500835,-0.0007518169,-0.0244758237,-0.1248556026,-0.0025091681,0.0679140056,0.0474680833,0.0161847762,0.0279416585,0.0052979053,0.0163553275,0.0066103855,0.0025421036,-0.0027881781,0.0296823066,-0.0015483471,-0.0130980392,0.0066225166,-0.0050900548,0.0046765394,-0.0038338158,0.0101456010,0.0283693280,0.0118233195,-0.0150200015,0.0018081820,-0.0184147932,0.0064039033,0.0161266127,-0.0058091286,0.0050292749,0.0067844628,0.0000000000,-0.0071332032,-0.0181178809,-0.0071604558,0.0026875528,-0.0128324778,0.0222796745,-0.0155212355,0.0086503866,-0.0086479809,-0.0025545750,0.0034714187,-0.0006175222,0.0074318112,-0.0104513432,0.0065374558,-0.0059574468,0.0156130998)

forecast_wn = c(0.003838468,0.003819081,0.003838570,0.003836313,0.003791836,0.003865645,0.003882838,0.003854259,0.003822018,0.003786571,0.003795024,
0.003816380,0.003801616,0.003814887,0.003806718,0.003773104,0.003806926,0.003737138,0.003689363,0.003710197,0.003670776,0.003671394,
0.003659132,0.003683619,0.003602766,0.003646462,0.003635128,0.003603160,0.003611586,0.003571343,0.003566889,0.003470289,0.003458191,
0.003378380,0.003013041,0.002997353,0.003181253,0.003306357,0.003342634,0.003411732,0.003417016,0.003453156,0.003461951,0.003459395,
0.003442089,0.003514576,0.003500629,0.003455028,0.003463706,0.003440335,0.003443703,0.003423927,0.003442143,0.003509514,0.003531923,
0.003482053,0.003477565,0.003419029,0.003426989,0.003460765,0.003436176,0.003440390,0.003449214,0.003440137,0.003412385,0.003356024,
0.003328565,0.003326896,0.003284924,0.003334133,0.003285411,0.003299238,0.003268526,0.003253595,0.003254152,0.003244275,0.003254930,
0.003220143,0.003228541,0.003205344)

forecast_nn = c(-0.0055742370,0.0158053225,0.0131748284,-0.0037854409,0.0151352256,-0.0028655890,0.0017027026,0.0127561264,0.0069359377,
0.0064302675,0.0129493060,-0.0107558082,0.0177475651,0.0074675720,0.0042049967,0.0104959131,0.0061647484,0.0273562074,
-0.0298913539,-0.0027861523,-0.0034990786,-0.0078612675,0.0136435813,-0.0133381446,0.0218311663,0.0011608844,-0.0076247119,
0.0212541515,-0.0095312359,-0.0057810926,0.0052415389,-0.0396474175,-0.0239578101,-0.0059993996,-0.0582889012,-0.0142563977,
0.0034204033,0.0321841871,0.0228072932,0.0098939801,0.0277782414,0.0157948274,0.0088082394,0.0035054735,-0.0055461901,
-0.0094388197,-0.0054676945,0.0071107150,-0.0036656321,-0.0058958911,-0.0002254639,0.0109870903,-0.0080940848,-0.0027239072,
0.0031855604,-0.0055587381,0.0211536626,-0.0072454644,0.0108820874,0.0083630764,0.0015537198,-0.0073377180,-0.0001160707,
0.0023619604,0.0090099197,-0.0196249917,-0.0290056639,0.0010064923,0.0205880529,0.0028138888,0.0066251122,-0.0048052213,
0.0029243110,-0.0059962882,-0.0003584435,0.0032325902,-0.0041919858,0.0151261213,-0.0038535528,0.0025962838)

sqrt(mean((data_test-forecast_nn)^2))
[1] 0.02340158

sqrt(mean((data_test-forecast_wn)^2))
[1] 0.02088056


train_data=c(
-0.0290370370,-0.0068615752,0.0074030204,0.0200232153,-0.0117439812,0.0249069568,0.0025699600,-0.0066110951,0.0108046631,
0.0067777464,-0.0088319088,0.0244580322,0.0024951483,-0.0061366806,0.0088471109,-0.0089260809,0.0115798180,0.0160065111,
-0.0148678414,0.0103542234,0.0083761146,-0.0046145494,0.0094111320,-0.0119727891,0.0110333692,0.0077436582,-0.0002670940,
-0.0113452188,0.0077727151,0.0077127660,-0.0002660282,0.0164835165,0.0052056221,0.0069785474,0.0170223577,0.0007616146,
0.0083081571,0.0231185440,0.0012281995,0.0075572891,0.0217028381,-0.0157461240,0.0346117867,0.0016343684,0.0025617140,
0.0240909091,0.0222222222,-0.0114632502,0.0040295500,0.0156456589,-0.0124944221,0.0239547038,0.0058454211,-0.0158346162,
0.0189859763,0.0030114003,0.0006448839,0.0064075182,0.0053112386,0.0195792543,0.0057983019,-0.0070907195,0.0149958915,
0.0059219931,-0.0115678579,0.0222177338,0.0004037957,0.0026178010,0.0207059752,-0.0011846002,0.0019704433,0.0221579961,
-0.0038684720,0.0015449981,0.0346756152,-0.0026168224,0.0031675051,0.0254221899,-0.0153023599,0.0163220892,0.0089863408,
-0.0155137799,0.0161608906,0.0058907533,0.0032028470,0.0030157885,0.0056447345,-0.0141323792,0.0088652482,-0.0014204545,
-0.0107681263,0.0193593805,-0.0069112174,0.0110410095,0.0033187773,-0.0057976107,0.0114623133,0.0135343498,0.0008558713,
0.0073067120,0.0180210245,0.0066302006,0.0013242841,0.0082088327,0.0113617919,0.0212867355,0.0095972310,0.0042299859,
0.0178488998,0.0016897081,0.0074706510,0.0311669129,-0.0166691695,0.0147950880,0.0171586448,-0.0008732353,0.0123616501,
0.0038659794,0.0002862869,-0.0012899527,-0.0120394546,-0.0045169751,-0.0104534747,-0.0065204505,-0.0019302153,-0.0120210368,
0.0032948929,-0.0183010523,0.0159087498,-0.0039174326,-0.0152975371,0.0215536596,0.0111012433,0.0041273585,0.0160986222,
-0.0081883316,0.0175262175,0.0082632854,-0.0001424907,0.0091769024,-0.0007064142,0.0128312413,-0.0161564626,0.0228500208,
-0.0041718815,0.0015273535,0.0035971223,0.0000000000,-0.0036101083,0.0170601883,-0.0148199446,0.0352752539,0.0162986330,
0.0023603462,0.0197943445,-0.0085558724,0.0191989828,0.0108162495,0.0081087824,0.0042236025,0.0169739895,-0.0052786644,
-0.0071711177,0.0124542125,0.0070320078,0.0118605487,0.0111361213,-0.0034474560,-0.0054984461,0.0041661707,0.0265353418,
0.0018505667,0.0038022814,-0.0103608847,0.0152470480,0.0073964497,0.0071178398,0.0113928292,0.0243025283,-0.0045982045,
0.0094349854,0.0127408994,0.0017101325,0.0024522870,0.0098184122,-0.0123984609,0.0139123103,0.0120783007,0.0003122723,
0.0146666667,0.0050005103,0.0041666667,0.0028374544,-0.0007098672,0.0046431816,0.0022157317,0.0055088141,0.0037916584,
0.0101728395,-0.0045639448,0.0114750883,0.0010776918,-0.0014717425,0.0268308985,-0.0079884504,-0.0169325634,0.0129456091,
-0.0032955316,-0.0079132474,0.0118737330,-0.0089607480,-0.0097364280,-0.0105346850,-0.0678127985,-0.0601935194,-0.0512123004,
-0.0010655932,-0.0041612175,0.0086044319,-0.0109628217,0.0245263280,0.0226084981,-0.0019351167,0.0342970210,0.0146230503,
0.0011900898,0.0261300179,-0.0019001372,0.0108593505,0.0193528569,-0.0001024066,0.0243780597,0.0124321658,-0.0053566114,
0.0027698091,0.0000000000,0.0160599572,0.0080139036,-0.0011599807,0.0128816794,-0.0048902100,0.0045814642,-0.0076945273,
0.0085820540,-0.0048869299,0.0077018161,0.0093255463,-0.0099895348,-0.0002854968,-0.0006666032,0.0007612523,-0.0018112488,
0.0052157421,0.0068751177,-0.0099876344,0.0261232052,-0.0093501636,-0.0024369669,-0.0002812676,0.0064275734,-0.0086441793,
0.0017820296,0.0014984079,0.0155803448,-0.0104331626,0.0063865235,0.0037805440,0.0002765487,-0.0102439933,0.0095923261,
0.0047732697,-0.0044255947,0.0101305102,0.0023672949,-0.0060456169,0.0119467825,-0.0020859786,-0.0043723811,0.0105452907,
-0.0028925246,-0.0009047317,0.0089661974,-0.0022465852,0.0173951435,-0.0023898035,-0.0017733641,0.0103545104,0.0004385580,
-0.0009657594,-0.0123544574,0.0040718775,-0.0121852881,0.0154375441,0.0015853444,-0.0016762241,0.0050908453,0.0059331646,
-0.0077376242,0.0095793782,-0.0142201025,0.0143640637,-0.0133203952,0.0063984574,-0.0042249802,0.0142299349,-0.0130087018,
0.0189704234,-0.0043301290,-0.0027789839,0.0224957555,0.0095013874,-0.0059206631,-0.0016944845,0.0196029571,-0.0136398080,
0.0166418281,-0.0013264799)


How do you calculate explained variance? If the RMSE of the flat line is lower than that of the NN, then the standard $R^2$ should be lower, since it's a simple monotonic transformation. Are you sure you used the holdout data for both calculations?

See this answer: the denominator is the same for both methods, since it does not depend on the forecast, only the actuals; and the numerator is just the sum of squared errors. So I don't see how one method could have a smaller RMSE and a smaller $R^2$ than another method. Unless you are calculating "explained variance" in some other way than $R^2$, or using some other data (e.g., one calculation using only holdout data, but the other one using in-sample).

Yes, you are right, the R^2 of the AR-NN is lower. I will post the original data and the forecasts to the original post, and also how I calculated the RMSE. @StephanKolassa

OK, but then the flatline forecast has a lower RMSE and explains more variance in the forecast. So it appears to be better. What then is your question? It is very common for the flat historical mean forecast to be better than more complex methods, whether ARIMA or ML-based.

@StephanKolassa The goal of the forecast is to predict the variations, of course. So shouldnt it be valid to say well yes, intercept-only is producing better forecasts, but the forecasts it produces is only helpful to a limited extent. If that is a valid point, then the question is if there is a metric that would support that argument?

Thanks. I have changed it.

However, the intercept-only model doesn't explain as much variance in its forecasts compared to the AR-NN model. How do you figure? What calculation (if it’s even a calculation) shows this?

@Dave That is wrong. Thanks for the hint, I edited it. The intercept-only model actually explains moreof the variance. However, its forecasts offer, of course, less variation than the AR-NN's.

@StephanKolassa true. I edited again. Thanks for all of the responses.

Thanks. I removed my comments, and added a few words to my answer.

Incidentally, since your title mentions both RMSE and MAE, you may be interested in this: Mean absolute error OR root mean squared error?

The $R^2$ of the flat line forecast is lower than that of the NN. So the flat forecast explains more variation than the NN. It is better. Case closed.

does it make sense to prefer the AR-NN model to obtain future forecasts that offer more variation even though being less accurate?

It depends. What are your ultimate aims in forecasting? If you need an accurate forecast, then your answer should be obvious: the flat line forecast is more accurate than the NN one. However, if you have strategic guidance to use AI/ML in forecasting, and this overrides the quest for accuracy (accuracy is rarely or never the only concern in forecasting), then it may well be prudent to use a more wiggly and more "interesting" ML forecast.
I know forecasters whose flat forecast was most accurate. But their customers complained that they could have calculated a historical mean themselves, so why were they paying an expensive expert? (Insert story about car mechanic and high invoice for simple operation here.) So the forecaster simply added some random noise to the flat line. This made the forecast worse, and the customer happy. See Kolassa (2023, Foresight).

Of course, it is unintuitive that a flat, non-varying, forecasts "explains variation" better than a variable NN forecast. This is because, at least to the best knowledge of your NN, there is no variation to be explained. The NN cannot explain any variation, it can only output variable forecasts that are noise (evidence: its RMSE is higher than that of the flat line forecast).
It is extremely common for flat historical mean forecasts to outperform more complex ones, whether ARIMA or ML-based: Is it unusual for the MEAN to outperform ARIMA? Even if your goal is to predict variations, that does not mean that you can do this with the information you have at hand. Your choice is between a better, less sexy flat forecast and a more "interesting" worse forecast that is more "interesting" solely because it injects useless noise.
If there is no variation that can be predicted based on the time series itself, you can start looking for external drivers that do so: How to know that your machine learning problem is hopeless?

So the forecaster simply added some random noise to the flat line. This made the forecast worse, and the customer happy. Amazing how the psychology factors into this.
